# AWS - Serialising temporary credentials and passing them through the chain of request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials, temporary

I am looking for a way to pass/propagate temporary credentials through a stack, down a chain of aws services. So that the middle components do no have permanent access and cannot initiate the process themsselves to get access to (sensitive) data in S3 buckets - they can only do so if they have been called by an application from the stack which itself has access; because none of the downstream components have the rights/ability to generate temporary credentials themselves, that means they are only trusted for the lifetime of the credentials.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You question is really really broad, you should add some context and try to be as specific as possible

Comment: Thank you @HenrikHolmgaardHøyer .Let's say we have an App A which is serving requests from end users, and wants to serve them by using component B.
 
So we want App A to make the calls to STS to get the temporary credentials.   
 
App A then makes a call to component B and passes the temporary credentials as part of this request, along with everything else needed.
 
Component B then uses the credentials that have been passed when it attempts to access the S3 bucket.